# How to use Scrapy to get text information from each link in list of links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a few pieces of text from each link. I have 600 links but only 2 here in this code.

usa-icon-list__content is the class that contains info I need, and the class is used multiple times on the page.

```
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tribe-spider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.bia.gov/bia/ois/tribal-leaders-directory/tribes/confederated-coos',
        'https://www.bia.gov/bia/ois/tribal-leaders-directory/tribes/confederated-yakama',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
        QUOTE_SELECTOR = '.usa-icon-list__content::text'
        
        for usa-icon-list__content in response.css(QUOTE_SELECTOR):
            yield {
                'text': usa-icon-list__content.css(TEXT_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            }
```

I just need to extract this info for every link but don't know if I'm using Scrapy correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that all the information you are seeking can be found from a single json source.  https://www.bia.gov/tribal-leaders-json

See below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tribe-spider'
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.bia.gov/tribal-leaders-json"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for tribe in response.json():
            yield tribe
```

PARTIAL OUTPUT::

```
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json> (referer: None)
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Bad River Band of the Lake Superior Tribe of Chippewa Indians of the Bad
 River Reservation, Wisconsin', 'Tribe': 'Bad River Band', 'TribeAlternateName': '', 'Triba
lComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Michael', 'MiddleName': '', 'LastName
': 'Wiggins', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': 'Chairman', 'Organization': '', 'BIARegi
on': 'Midwest', 'BIAAgency': 'Great Lakes Agency', 'PhysicalAddress': 'Chief Blackbird Cent
er 72682 Maple Street<br />\r\n<br />\r\n', 'City': 'Odanah', 'State': 'WI', 'ZIPCode': '54
861', 'Alaska': 'No', 'Phone': '(715) 682-7111', 'Fax': '(715) 682-7118', 'Email': 'mikew@b
adriver-nsn.gov', 'WebSite': 'http://www.badriver-nsn.gov/home', 'MailingAddress': 'Post Of
fice Box 39 ', 'MailingAddressCity': 'Odanah', 'MailingAddressState': 'Wisconsin', 'Mailing
AddressZIPCode': '54861', 'DateElected': '11/4/2021', 'NextElection': '11/4/2023', 'Directo
ry': 'Tribal', 'Notes': "Chairman's Assistant - Barb Smart brtsecretary@badriver-nsn-gov NO
TE: 5/4/2020 Shyla Joe Email. Edit TLD to match FR Notice.", 'ANCSARegion': '', 'BLMRegion'
: 'Eastern States', 'BORRegion': '', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 3 - Midwest', 'LCC': '', 'NPSRegi
on': 'Midwest', 'USGSRegion': 'Midwest', 'AlaskaSubsistenceRegion': '', 'Latitude': '46.608
3268', 'Longtitude': '-90.6969042'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Pribilof Islands Aleut Communities', 'Tribe': 'Pribilof Islands ', 'Trib
eAlternateName': '', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': '', 'Middle
Name': '', 'LastName': '', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': '', 'Organization': '', 'BI
ARegion': 'Alaska', 'BIAAgency': 'Alaska Regional Office', 'PhysicalAddress': 'Please refer
 to affiliates for contact information', 'City': '', 'State': '', 'ZIPCode': '', 'Alaska':
'Yes', 'Phone': '', 'Fax': '', 'Email': '', 'WebSite': '', 'MailingAddress': '', 'MailingAd
dressCity': '', 'MailingAddressState': 'Alaska', 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '', 'DateElected'
: '', 'NextElection': '', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': '', 'ANCSARegion': '', 'BLMRegion
': '', 'BORRegion': '', 'FWSRegion': '', 'LCC': '', 'NPSRegion': '', 'USGSRegion': '', 'Ala
skaSubsistenceRegion': '', 'Latitude': '57.18036020221606', 'Longtitude': '-170.25753032096
637'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Shoshone-Bannock Tribes of the Fort Hall Reservation', 'Tribe': 'Shoshon
e-Bannock', 'TribeAlternateName': '', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstN
ame': 'Lee', 'MiddleName': 'Juan', 'LastName': 'Tyler ', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle
': 'Chairman', 'Organization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Northwest', 'BIAAgency': 'Fort Hall Agency
', 'PhysicalAddress': 'Agency Building 82 1 Pima Drive', 'City': 'Fort Hall', 'State': 'ID'
, 'ZIPCode': '83203', 'Alaska': 'No', 'Phone': '(208) 478-3700', 'Fax': '(208) 237-0797', '
Email': 'ltyler@sbtribes.com', 'WebSite': 'http://www.shoshonebannocktribes.com', 'MailingA
ddress': 'P.O. Box 306 ', 'MailingAddressCity': 'Fort Hall', 'MailingAddressState': 'Idaho'
, 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '83203-0306', 'DateElected': '6/14/2023', 'NextElection': '5/26/
2024', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': '', 'ANCSARegion': '', 'BLMRegion': 'Idaho', 'BORReg
ion': 'Columbia-Pacific Northwest', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 1 - Pacific', 'LCC': '', 'NPSRegio
n': 'Pacific West', 'USGSRegion': 'Northwest', 'AlaskaSubsistenceRegion': '', 'Latitude': '
42.99', 'Longtitude': '-112.46'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Eastern Shawnee Tribe of Oklahoma', 'Tribe': 'Eastern Shawnee Tribe of O
klahoma', 'TribeAlternateName': 'Eastern Shawnee', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation'
: '', 'FirstName': 'Glenna', 'MiddleName': 'J.', 'LastName': 'Wallace', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka'
: '', 'JobTitle': 'Chief', 'Organization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Eastern Oklahoma', 'BIAAgency'
: 'Miami Agency', 'PhysicalAddress': '127 West Oneida ', 'City': 'Seneca', 'State': 'MO', '
ZIPCode': '64865', 'Alaska': 'No', 'Phone': '(918) 666-2435', 'Fax': '(918) 666-2186', 'Ema
il': 'gjwallace@estoo.net', 'WebSite': 'http://www.estoo-nsn.gov', 'MailingAddress': 'P.O.
Box 350 ', 'MailingAddressCity': 'Seneca', 'MailingAddressState': 'Missouri', 'MailingAddre
ssZIPCode': '64865', 'DateElected': '9/8/2018', 'NextElection': '9/10/2022', 'Directory': '
Tribal', 'Notes': '', 'ANCSARegion': '', 'BLMRegion': 'Eastern States', 'BORRegion': 'Misso
uri Basin', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 3 - Midwest', 'LCC': 'Eastern Tallgrass Prairie and Big Ri
vers', 'NPSRegion': 'Midwest', 'USGSRegion': 'Midwest', 'AlaskaSubsistenceRegion': '', 'Lat
itude': '36.8015396', 'Longtitude': '-94.5830789'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Pueblo of Sandia, New Mexico', 'Tribe': 'Pueblo of Sandia', 'TribeAltern
ateName': 'NA-FIAT', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Stuart', '
MiddleName': '', 'LastName': 'Paisano', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': 'Governor', 'O
rganization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Southwest', 'BIAAgency': 'Southern Pueblos Agency', 'Physic
alAddress': '481 Sandia Loop  ', 'City': 'Bernalillo', 'State': 'NM', 'ZIPCode': '87004', '
Alaska': 'No', 'Phone': '(505) 867-3317', 'Fax': '(505) 867-9235', 'Email': 'govspaisano@sa
ndiapueblo.nsn.us', 'WebSite': '', 'MailingAddress': '481 Sandia Loop ', 'MailingAddressCit
y': 'Bernalillo', 'MailingAddressState': 'New Mexico', 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '87004', 'D
ateElected': '', 'NextElection': '', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': '', 'ANCSARegion': '',
 'BLMRegion': 'New Mexico', 'BORRegion': 'Upper Colorado', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 2 - Southwe
st', 'LCC': 'Southern Rockies', 'NPSRegion': 'Intermountain', 'USGSRegion': 'Southwest', 'A
laskaSubsistenceRegion': '', 'Latitude': '35.254944', 'Longtitude': '-106.572887'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Galena Village (aka Louden Village)', 'Tribe': 'Galena', 'TribeAlternate
Name': 'Louden Village', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Charli
e', 'MiddleName': '', 'LastName': 'Green', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': '1st Chief'
, 'Organization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Alaska', 'BIAAgency': 'Fairbanks Agency', 'PhysicalAddr
ess': '100 Front Street', 'City': '', 'State': '', 'ZIPCode': '', 'Alaska': 'Yes', 'Phone':
 '(907) 656-1711', 'Fax': '(907) 656-2491', 'Email': 'office@loudentribe.com;', 'WebSite':
'', 'MailingAddress': 'P.O. Box 44 ', 'MailingAddressCity': 'Galena', 'MailingAddressState'
: 'Alaska', 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '99741', 'DateElected': '4/1/2017', 'NextElection': '4
/1/2020', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': '3 year term', 'ANCSARegion': 'Doyon Ltd.', 'BLMR
egion': 'Alaska', 'BORRegion': '', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 7 - Alaska', 'LCC': 'Northwest Bore
al', 'NPSRegion': 'Alaska', 'USGSRegion': 'Alaska', 'AlaskaSubsistenceRegion': 'Western Int
erior', 'Latitude': '64.7333', 'Longtitude': '-156.9275'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Nunakauyarmiut Tribe', 'Tribe': 'Nunakauyarmiut', 'TribeAlternateName':
'', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Moses', 'MiddleName': '', '
LastName': 'Chanar', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': 'President', 'Organization': '',
'BIARegion': 'Alaska', 'BIAAgency': 'Alaska Regional Office', 'PhysicalAddress': '101 Sunny
 Street', 'City': 'Toksook Bay', 'State': 'AK', 'ZIPCode': '99637-7048', 'Alaska': 'Yes', '
Phone': '(907) 427-7114', 'Fax': '(907) 427-7714', 'Email': 'robert@ntcak.com', 'WebSite':
'', 'MailingAddress': 'P.O. Box 37048 ', 'MailingAddressCity': 'Toksook Bay', 'MailingAddre
ssState': 'Alaska', 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '99637-0048', 'DateElected': '10/25/2022', 'Ne
xtElection': '10/2023', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': "President's term ends 2024", 'ANCS
ARegion': 'Calista Corp.', 'BLMRegion': 'Alaska', 'BORRegion': '', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 7 -
 Alaska', 'LCC': 'Western Alaska', 'NPSRegion': 'Alaska', 'USGSRegion': 'Alaska', 'AlaskaSu
bsistenceRegion': 'Yukon-Kuskokwim Delta', 'Latitude': '60.5303', 'Longtitude': '-165.1025'
}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Village of Sleetmute', 'Tribe': 'Sleetmute', 'TribeAlternateName': 'Slee
tmute Traditional Council', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Ell
en', 'MiddleName': '', 'LastName': 'Yako', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': 'President'
, 'Organization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Alaska', 'BIAAgency': 'Alaska Regional Office', 'Physic
alAddress': ' ', 'City': '', 'State': '', 'ZIPCode': '', 'Alaska': 'Yes', 'Phone': '(907) 4
49-4263', 'Fax': '(907) 449-4265', 'Email': 'slqtraditionalcouncil@gmail.com; madisonmellic
k@sleetmutetc.', 'WebSite': '', 'MailingAddress': 'P.O. Box 109 ', 'MailingAddressCity': 'S
leetmute', 'MailingAddressState': 'Alaska', 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '99668', 'DateElected'
: '7/15/2108', 'NextElection': '12/31/2018', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': 'Three year te
rm', 'ANCSARegion': 'Calista Corp.', 'BLMRegion': 'Alaska', 'BORRegion': '', 'FWSRegion': '
Region 7 - Alaska', 'LCC': 'Northwest Boreal', 'NPSRegion': 'Alaska', 'USGSRegion': 'Alaska
', 'AlaskaSubsistenceRegion': 'Western Interior', 'Latitude': '61.7025', 'Longtitude': '-15
7.1697'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Native Village of Nightmute', 'Tribe': 'Nightmute', 'TribeAlternateName'
: '', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Isadore', 'MiddleName': '
', 'LastName': 'Anthony', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': 'President', 'Organization':
 '', 'BIARegion': 'Alaska', 'BIAAgency': 'Alaska Regional Office', 'PhysicalAddress': '101
Changtak Street ', 'City': 'Nightmute', 'State': 'AK', 'ZIPCode': '99690', 'Alaska': 'Yes',
 'Phone': '(907) 647-6215', 'Fax': '(907) 647-6112', 'Email': 'negtemiut_tribe@live.com', '
WebSite': '', 'MailingAddress': 'P.O. Box 90021', 'MailingAddressCity': 'Nightmute', 'Maili
ngAddressState': 'Alaska', 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '99690', 'DateElected': '11/1/2017', 'N
extElection': '11/1/2019', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': 'election listed as month/year',
 'ANCSARegion': 'Calista Corp.', 'BLMRegion': 'Alaska', 'BORRegion': '', 'FWSRegion': 'Regi
on 7 - Alaska', 'LCC': 'Western Alaska', 'NPSRegion': 'Alaska', 'USGSRegion': 'Alaska', 'Al
askaSubsistenceRegion': 'Yukon-Kuskokwim Delta', 'Latitude': '60.4794', 'Longtitude': '-164
.7239'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Native Village of Diomede (aka Inalik)', 'Tribe': 'Diomede', 'TribeAlter
nateName': 'Inalik', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Robert', '
MiddleName': 'F.', 'LastName': 'Soolook', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': 'President',
 'Organization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Alaska', 'BIAAgency': 'Alaska Regional Office', 'Physica
lAddress': ' ', 'City': '', 'State': '', 'ZIPCode': '', 'Alaska': 'Yes', 'Phone': '(907) 68
6-2175', 'Fax': '(907) 686-2203', 'Email': 'tc.dio@kawerak.org', 'WebSite': '', 'MailingAdd
ress': 'P.O. Box 7079 ', 'MailingAddressCity': 'Diomede', 'MailingAddressState': 'Alaska',
'MailingAddressZIPCode': '99762', 'DateElected': '1/1/2014', 'NextElection': '', 'Directory
': 'Tribal', 'Notes': 'While updating the tribe informed us that Robert w', 'ANCSARegion':
'Bering Straits Native Corp.', 'BLMRegion': 'Alaska', 'BORRegion': '', 'FWSRegion': 'Region
 7 - Alaska', 'LCC': 'Western Alaska', 'NPSRegion': 'Alaska', 'USGSRegion': 'Alaska', 'Alas
kaSubsistenceRegion': 'Seward Peninsula', 'Latitude': '65.7582', 'Longtitude': '-168.9519'}

2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Iqugmiut Traditional Council', 'Tribe': 'Iqugmiut', 'TribeAlternateName'
: '', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Wassily', 'MiddleName': '
', 'LastName': 'Alexie', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': 'President', 'Organization':
'', 'BIARegion': 'Alaska', 'BIAAgency': 'Alaska Regional Office', 'PhysicalAddress': 'P.O.
Box 09 ', 'City': 'Russian Mission', 'State': 'AK', 'ZIPCode': '99657', 'Alaska': 'Yes', 'P
hone': '(907) 584-5511', 'Fax': '(907) 584-5593', 'Email': 'iqurmiut71@yahoo.com', 'WebSite
': '', 'MailingAddress': 'P.O. Box 09', 'MailingAddressCity': 'Russian Mission', 'MailingAd
dressState': 'Alaska', 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '99657', 'DateElected': '10/1/2018', 'NextE
lection': '10/1/2019', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': 'President has a three year term', '
ANCSARegion': 'Calista Corp.', 'BLMRegion': 'Alaska', 'BORRegion': '', 'FWSRegion': 'Region
 7 - Alaska', 'LCC': 'Western Alaska', 'NPSRegion': 'Alaska', 'USGSRegion': 'Alaska', 'Alas
kaSubsistenceRegion': 'Yukon-Kuskokwim Delta', 'Latitude': '61.785', 'Longtitude': '-161.32
03'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Shinnecock Indian Nation', 'Tribe': 'Shinnecock', 'TribeAlternateName':
'', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'Bryan', 'MiddleName': '', '
LastName': 'Polite; Randall King; Donald Williams, Jr.,', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitl
e': 'Council of Trustees', 'Organization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Eastern', 'BIAAgency': 'Easter
n Regional Office', 'PhysicalAddress': '100 Church Street, Community Center Shinnecock Rese
rvation', 'City': 'Southampton', 'State': 'NY', 'ZIPCode': '11968', 'Alaska': 'No', 'Phone'
: '631-283-6143', 'Fax': '631-283-0751', 'Email': 'adminoffice@shinnecock.org', 'WebSite':
'', 'MailingAddress': 'Shinnecock Indian Nation Tribal Office P.O. Box 5006', 'MailingAddre
ssCity': 'Southampton', 'MailingAddressState': 'New York', 'MailingAddressZIPCode': '11969-
5006', 'DateElected': 'July 2020', 'NextElection': 'April 2022', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'No
tes': 'Elections are every 2 years', 'ANCSARegion': '', 'BLMRegion': 'Eastern States', 'BOR
Region': '', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 5 - Northeast', 'LCC': '', 'NPSRegion': 'Northeast', 'USG
SRegion': 'Northeast', 'AlaskaSubsistenceRegion': '', 'Latitude': '40.88', 'Longtitude': '-
72.39'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Otoe-Missouria Tribe of Indians, Oklahoma', 'Tribe': 'Otoe-Missouria', '
TribeAlternateName': '', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation': '', 'FirstName': 'John',
 'MiddleName': 'R.', 'LastName': 'Shotton', 'Suffix': '', 'Aka': '', 'JobTitle': 'Chairman'
, 'Organization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Southern Plains', 'BIAAgency': 'Pawnee Agency', 'Physic
alAddress': '8151 Highway 177  ', 'City': 'Red Rock', 'State': 'OK', 'ZIPCode': '74651-0348
', 'Alaska': 'No', 'Phone': '(580) 723-4466', 'Fax': '(580) 723-4273', 'Email': 'jshotton@o
mtribe.org', 'WebSite': 'http://www.omtribe.org', 'MailingAddress': '8151 Highway 177 ', 'M
ailingAddressCity': 'Red Rock', 'MailingAddressState': 'Oklahoma', 'MailingAddressZIPCode':
 '74651-0348', 'DateElected': '11/2/2019', 'NextElection': '11/1/2022', 'Directory': 'Triba
l', 'Notes': '', 'ANCSARegion': '', 'BLMRegion': 'New Mexico', 'BORRegion': 'Missouri Basin
', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 2 - Southwest', 'LCC': '', 'NPSRegion': 'Intermountain', 'USGSRegio
n': 'Southwest', 'AlaskaSubsistenceRegion': '', 'Latitude': '36.4913525', 'Longtitude': '-9
7.0748296'}
2023-10-07 11:12:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.bia.gov/trib
al-leaders-json>
{'TribeFullName': 'Ewiiaapaayp Band of Kumeyaay Indians, California', 'Tribe': 'Ewiiaapaayp
', 'TribeAlternateName': 'Cuyapaipe Reservation', 'TribalComponent': 'Tribe', 'Salutation':
 '', 'FirstName': 'Robert', 'MiddleName': '', 'LastName': 'Pinto', 'Suffix': 'Sr.', 'Aka':
'', 'JobTitle': 'Chairman', 'Organization': '', 'BIARegion': 'Pacific', 'BIAAgency': 'Pacif
ic Regional Office', 'PhysicalAddress': '4054 Willows Road  ', 'City': 'Alpine', 'State': '
CA', 'ZIPCode': '91901', 'Alaska': 'No', 'Phone': '(619) 445-6315', 'Fax': '(619) 445-9126'
, 'Email': 'ceo@leaningrock.com', 'WebSite': '', 'MailingAddress': '4054 Willows Road ', 'M
ailingAddressCity': 'Alpine', 'MailingAddressState': 'California', 'MailingAddressZIPCode':
 '91901', 'DateElected': '', 'NextElection': '', 'Directory': 'Tribal', 'Notes': 'Actual el
ection date TBD.', 'ANCSARegion': '', 'BLMRegion': 'California', 'BORRegion': 'Lower Colora
do', 'FWSRegion': 'Region 8 - Pacific Southwest', 'LCC': '', 'NPSRegion': 'Pacific West', '
USGSRegion': 'Pacific', 'AlaskaSubsistenceRegion': '', 'Latitude': '32.836279', 'Longtitude
': '-116.726317'}
```